# Most efficient way to convert list of values to probability distribution?

Tags: python, numpy

I have several lists that can only contain the following values: 0, 0.5, 1, 1.5

I want to efficiently convert each of these lists into probability mass functions. So if a list is as follows: [0.5, 0.5, 1, 1.5], the PMF will look like this: [0, 0.5, 0.25, 0.25].

I need to do this many times (and with very large lists), so avoiding looping will be optimal, if at all possible. What's the most efficient way to make this happen?

Edit: Here's my current system. This feels like a really inefficient/unelegant way to do it:

```
def get_distribution(samplemodes1):
    
    n, bin_edges = np.histogram(samplemodes1, bins = 9)
    totalcount = np.sum(n)
    bin_probability = n / totalcount
    bins_per_point = np.fmin(np.digitize(samplemodes1, bin_edges), len(bin_edges)-1)
    probability_perpoint = [bin_probability[bins_per_point[i]-1] for i in range(len(samplemodes1))] 
    
    counts = Counter(samplemodes1)
    total = sum(counts.values())
    
    probability_mass = {k:v/total for k,v in counts.items()}
    #print(probability_mass)
    
    key_values = {}
    
    if(0 in probability_mass):
        key_values[0] = probability_mass.get(0)
    else:
        key_values[0] = 0
    if(0.5 in probability_mass):
        key_values[0.5] = probability_mass.get(0.5)
    else:
        key_values[0.5] = 0
    if(1 in probability_mass):
        key_values[1] = probability_mass.get(1)
    else:
        key_values[1] = 0
    if(1.5 in probability_mass):
        key_values[1.5] = probability_mass.get(1.5)  
    else:
        key_values[1.5] = 0
        
        
    distribution = list(key_values.values())
    return distribution
```

Comment: Do you have code you can share, even inefficient code, that would precisely define the output you need?

Comment: My intuition would be to start with `collections.Counter` and convert it to your four-element list with a comprehension after, but you'd have to benchmark to see how fast it is.

Comment: NumPy might be more efficient because there are vectorized options: https://thispointer.com/count-occurrences-of-a-value-in-numpy-array-in-python/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some solution for you to benchmark:

##### Using `collections.Counter`

```
from collections import Counter

bins = [0, 0.5, 1, 1.5]
a = [0.5, 0.5, 1.0, 0.5, 1.0, 1.5, 0.5]
denom = len(a)
counts = Counter(a)
pmf = [counts[bin]/denom for bin in Bins]
```

##### NumPy based solution

```
import numpy as np

bins = [0, 0.5, 1, 1.5]
a = np.array([0.5, 0.5, 1.0, 0.5, 1.0, 1.5, 0.5])
denom = len(a)
pmf = [(a == bin).sum()/denom for bin in bins]
```

but you can probably do better by using `np.bincount()` instead.

Further reading on this idea: https://thispointer.com/count-occurrences-of-a-value-in-numpy-array-in-python/

Comment: Great, thanks! For the NumPy based solution, should we be dividing by the sum of the array in order to convert this to a PMF (where all values add up to 1)?

Comment: Yeah, I just noticed that too, for both solution. Edit done.